# validates length of a Comment, but without error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

To begin I'm sorry for my english :)

Well, i'm actually learning Rails with a simple application, the famous blog.

Here is the actual database schema :

```
create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "post_id"
t.text     "text"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "text"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Post model :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :comments

    validates_presence_of :title, :message => "title is mandatory"
    validates :text, :length => { :minimum => 10 }
end
```

And when I try to create a Post with a text <= 10 chars, as expected, it doesn't save the Post, and I get an error message (by default).

So I tried to do the same with a Comment...

Comment model :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :post
     validates :text, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 10 }        
end
```

And my CommentsController :

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
   @comment.save

   redirect_to @post
  end

  def destroy
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   @comment.destroy

   redirect_to @comment.post
  end
end
```

I know that the validation is executed because I can't create a comment with a content <= 10 chars, however I didn't get an error message as expected. And that's what I'm trying to get...

Thanks.

Comment: how do you know there's no error message ? did you try this through the console ? I suspect that since you're redirecting to `@post`, you render the `Post#show` action view which may not handle error message for associated objects.

Comment: How could I handle error message for this inside Post#show ?

Comment: how do you display error messages?

Comment: eduke if you wanna handle error message you have to use the following code snippet.This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The Following code :

```
def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
   begin
    @comment.save!
     redirect_to @post
    rescue Exception => error
     puts "Error:: #{error.message}"
     render : new #to not redirect
    end
```

Your error will be puts to your console.

If you wanna see this errors to the View then add this to your 'new'

```
<div>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
    <%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```